# get value only from "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1" while using componentsSeparatedByString,sigabrt occurs?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

my string value is this 
// The string should be something like `"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.5 0 0.25 1"`

i'm parsing the string to get the color value alone

```
 -(UIColor*)colorFromNSString:(NSString *)string {


        NSMutableArray *values = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
        CGFloat red = [[values objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        CGFloat green = [[values objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
       CGFloat blue = [[values objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
      CGFloat alpha = [[values objectAtIndex:4] floatValue];
      UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
   //     NSLog(@"the color in string is %@",red);
       return color;
}
```

i'm geting the error msg of sigabrt in this line

```
NSMutableArray *values = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
```

crash log is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4a3e0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dcf5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f23313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dd10bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d40966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d40522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   PhotoApp                            0x00002800 -[PhotoAppViewController colorFromNSString:] + 67
    6   PhotoApp                            0x000027b5 -[PhotoAppViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 950
    7   UIKit                               0x0038d0f4 forwardMethod2 + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x002e3d41 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 395
    9   UIKit                               0x002c4c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    10  UIKit                               0x002c9f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x01727992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00db0944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00d10cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
```

any suggestion welcome

Comment: Are you sure it's `@""` not `@" "`?

Comment: @Arungre you tried and then what ? SIGABRT is not enough debugging info you are giving us. Post crash log here.

Comment: 0x8badf00d  i've sent for you

Comment: @Arungre looking at your crash log it says componentsSeperatedByString: message is passed to NSArray class object which is unrecognized selector. But in your code it looks like you are passing it to a string object. Can you make these changes in your code: add NSString * clsName = NSStringFromClass([string class]); NSLog(@"Class Name is: %@",clsName); NSArray * values = [string componentsSeperatedByString:@" "]; and run your application.

Comment: 0x8badf00d - no changes same issue, anyother solution

Comment: @Arungre What does NSLog says ? Class Name is: ? How are you calling -[PhotoAppViewController colorFromNSString:] what are you passing to it ? Are you sure its NSString that you are passing to this method ? or is it NSArray object

Comment: (UIColor*)colorFromNSString:(NSString *)string--here i'm passing a string value- string is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.5 0 0.25 1"

Comment: How are you passing the string show us some more code.

Comment: can i have your email id we will chat in gmail

Comment: -(NSString *)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count1:(int)count-from here i;m getting the string value

Comment: Sure. Its testusermac123@gmail.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 CGColorRef coloref = [selectst CGColor];
     const CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(coloref);

    CGFloat red = components[0];
    CGFloat green = components[1];
    CGFloat blue = components[2];
    CGFloat alpha =1;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIColor*)colorFromNSString:(NSString *)string {

    NSArray *myarray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSLog(@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:1]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:2]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:3]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:4]);
    CGFloat red = [[myarray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    CGFloat green = [[myarray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    CGFloat blue = [[myarray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
    CGFloat alpha = [[myarray objectAtIndex:4] floatValue];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];

    return color;
}
```